# Prevent aggressive auto-scaling in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, scale, matlab-figure

Say I have the following Matlab code:

```
figure;
a=plot(1:10); %A
pause();
set(a,'ydata',1:2:20); %B
pause();
set(a,'ydata',1:10); %C
```

At (A) the vertical range of my plot is [1,10].
At (B) the vertical range of my plot is [0,20].
At (C), the vertical range is once again [1,10].

I like that the plot auto-scales from step (A) to (B).  I don't like the auto-scaling from (B) to (C) - it makes things jump around too much.

Is there a way to have set the plot's scale to expand but never shrink?

In my mind, this looks like:

```
set(gca,'XLimMode','auto_maxever');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my knowledge, Matlab does not have a function such as you describe, however...

You can set exactly the limits of `X` and `Y` by doing the following command:

```
set(gca,'XLim',[x1 x2], 'YLim',[y1 y2]);
```

A quick alias for the very same command is:

```
axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax]);
```

You might as well "freeze" the limits at any moment you like, by changing the `XLimMode` and `YLimMode` from `Auto` to `Manual`:

```
figure();
a=plot(1:10); %A
pause();
set(a,'ydata',1:2:20); %B
pause();
set(gca,'XLimMode','manual');
set(gca,'YLimMode','manual');
set(a,'ydata',1:10); %C
```

Or you can use yet another alias, which does exactly the same:

```
axis('manual');
```

If data is being continuously acquired, consider saving the axis limits before each update and then performing manual scaling.

Comment: Hmmm... ideally, I would like to say: `set(gca,'XLimMode','auto_maxever');` And have it perform the function I described: expand but never shrink.

Comment: @Richard, you could calculate the bounding box of your data beforehand

Comment: The data is being continuously acquired, @Andrey.

Comment: @Richard, You can store it in a variable and update it each time.

Comment: That turned out to be the only feasible solution I could find, @Andrey, thank you.

Comment: Any idea how to apply that for `bar` diagrams?

Comment: I opened a new thread about the issue in functions which are plotting new objects here http://stackoverflow.com/q/36220082/54964 I do not know if we can control them.